# Start menu doesn't appear

Tags: windows-10-preview

I've tried almost everything on [the list from this blog](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_search/start-menu-doesnt-appear/a7c56613-277c-4993-bb74-08650dce7b21?page=7) but it seems that my Start menu isn't going to show. I get nothing when I press <kbd>Win</kbd> with other keys, like <kbd>S</kbd> for search or <kbd>C</kbd> for charms menu. However I get it to work with <kbd>X</kbd> for the context menu over the Start button as well as with <kbd>L</kbd> for locking the computer.

Using build 9926 on Surface 3.

Comment: This is a known issue with this build.  It will eventually be fixed in a future build.

Comment: But it worked until today... Same build. Different behavior. Weird... Also, how do I get the update once it comes? I can't start the windows update without the Start menu working, can I?

Comment: Just navigate to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items` in an explorer window. Windows 10 doesn't have charms.

Comment: The "Change settings" for Windows Update is grayed out. I'm not sure how to make it look for new updates...

Comment: It does not sound like you are logged in as an `Administrator`.

Comment: Hmm... I might be hitting another bug in Win10. I'm the only account on the system, according to the control panel's users section I'm an admin, I can run stuff as admin, I can assign other users as admins... Is it possible to **download and install offline** any of the updates?

Comment: These are not updates but patches; unlikely to have offline versions

Comment: Hmm... Now I'm worried. Since the button is grayed out **and** I won't be able to get them off-line, I feel a problem heading towards me...   :(